# How to bring GuideGuide plugin on side panel

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have installed *GuideGuide* plugin. I am a photoshop noob.

I don't know where would I access it? I have create a new workspace **Web Development**

I wish to add *GuideGuide* Plugin on right side bar for easy access. How would I do that?

Basically, I don't even know where the plugin is(in Menu options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If installed correctly, the GuideGuide panel can be opened via `Window > Extensions > GuideGuide`. From there you can manipulate it like any other panel.